# Combining identical monitors to form one large display

Tags: monitors, multiple-monitors, splitters

So I got a whole bunch of monitors (A LOT) and from the collection there are about 6 identical 17" 4/3 ratio monitors that I wish to make a grid from (3x2 forming 12/6 or 2/1 wide ratio). I want all six displays to form one display and be connected to one port on my computer. So in other words, I want them acting as sub-displays.

I know it is possible to achieve this using software and by having all monitors connected directly to the computer. But I do not have enough ports for them and I am using GTX 1080 to handle my 3 main displays setup (this should be an extra). And I also wish for the configuration to work with my laptop when necessary (has HDMI port).

Therefore, is there a hardware setup that is affordable and can be used to unify these monitors as one? If so, where can I find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there a hardware setup that is affordable

The kind of device you are looking for is called a [Video Wall Controller](https://www.google.com/search?q=video+wall+controller) and they are typically a commercial-use device for store signage, billboards, restaurant menus, etc.

Many of them are actually standalone devices that render their own output from a video file or website, and do not always support direct video input. Make sure you any model you are interested in *does* have a video input.

They are in the ball park of $1000 for one that can do up to 8 displays.

---

> But I do not have enough ports for them and I am using GTX 1080 to handle my 3 main displays setup

You can sometimes install more than one GPU in a computer, and for $1000 you could definitely find a GPU that supports 6 displays using DisplayPort outputs. Many GPUs can support small (2x2, 1x3, etc) video walls with hardware acceleration, so it is a proper "hardware" solution. Each monitor will probably also need an **active** DisplayPort adapter unless they have a DisplayPort input.